# Background Image rotation with pre-loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need 10 background images (covering) to rotate in the background of a website.

They will be around 200k each, so we don't want to see them loading.

How can I do use Javascript (or JQuery) to force all, or some, images to preload, and perhaps not do the rotation if bandwidth is low?

Thanks.

Comment: Use an [imageloader](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/) to preload your images.

Comment: Thanks. Actually on reflection rotating either after 5 seconds OR when the next image has loaded, whichever is longer would make most sense.

Comment: Image loader looks interesting - what if preloading all 10 images takes 20 seconds, is the user waiting 20 seconds to see anything?

Comment: The user waits 20 seconds to see the background images, the rest (if applicable) will be loaded normally.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to load all images using JavaScript. Apply images as background loading is completed

```
function preloader() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.background = "url(http://domain.tld/image01.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.background = "url(http://domain.tld/image02.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.background = "url(http://domain.tld/image03.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);

//Now loop these images

var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = 'http://domain.tld/image01.png';
backgrounds[1] = 'http://domain.tld/image02.png';
backgrounds[2] = 'http://domain.tld/image03.png';

function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground > 2) currentBackground = 0;

    $('body').fadeOut(100,function() {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('body').fadeIn(100);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);        
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between `$(document).ready(function() {` and the function `addLoadEvent`? And `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a nodeList.

Comment: thanks - forgot to mention, need to fade to black between images too